# Is it possible to make adiscord button one time use? In discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So is it possible to make an discord.py Button a one time use. If its possible let me know how?

Answer (score -2):

Actually, making buttons in discord.py isn't really possible. If you want to make buttons, you have to uninstall discord.py and install a fork like pycord or nextcord.

Comment: But i did it???

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment, once you reach sufficient reputation you'll be able to use write them. However, you *can* make buttons with `discord.py` if you install the github version which isn't posted on PyPI.